SSJS QueueMO - The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request
I've been trying to get a POST call to the sms/v1/queueMO endpoint (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_sms/postQueueMO.html) to work from a Cloudpage and Code Snippet, without any luck.
This is my code:
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
  Platform.Load("core", "1");
  function getAccessToken() {
    var ClientId = 'XXXXXX';
    var ClientSecret = 'YYYYYY';
    var url = 'https://ZZZZZ.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token';
    var ContentType = 'application/json';
    var payload = {
      "client_id": ClientId,
      "client_secret": ClientSecret,
      "grant_type": "client_credentials"
    };
    try {
      var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Post(url, ContentType, Stringify(payload));
      var statusCode = accessTokenResult["StatusCode"];
      var response = accessTokenResult["Response"][0];
      var accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).access_token;
      Variable.SetValue("@accessToken", accessToken);
      return accessToken;
    }
    catch (e) {
      Write(e.message);
    }
  }

  try {
 
            var accesstoken = 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken();
            if (accesstoken) { 
                var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
                var headerValues = [accesstoken];

                var requestBody = {
                    "mobileNumbers": ["11111"],
                    "shortCode": "222222",
                    "messageText": "somekeyword"
                }; 

                var httpResponse = HTTP.Post("https://zzzz.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/sms/v1/queueMO/", "application/json", Stringify(requestBody), headerNames, headerValues);

                var statusCode = httpResponse["StatusCode"];
                var journeyHistoryResponse = httpResponse["Response"][0];
                    

                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                Write(Stringify(e));
            }
  
  
</script>

The token part is working fine and i can see it in the accesstoken parameter.
Also, it is working from POSTMAN but when i run it in a cloudpage i get this error:
--- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\nSystem.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. - from System
I'm sure someone already got this working!
Thank you
